# PHP ZKLib undefined function socket_create()

Tags: php, websocket, sdk, biometrics

I am  starting doing a simple project using [ZKTeco](https://www.zkteco.com) and its SDK for PHP or online SDK to connect the data from biometrics to our database. I try to use then https://github.com/dnaextrim/php_zklib because almost of the discussion from googling link to this.

Now I got an error:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> socket_create() in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib-master\zklib\zklib.php:16
> Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib-master\zktest.php(10):
> ZKLib->__construct('192.168.5.164', 4370) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\php_zklib-master\zklib\zklib.php on line 16
```

What is the following cause of this error and what is the following solution about this?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using xampp enable php_sockets.dll by removing ';' from ;extension=php_sockets.dll in php.ini file and restart the xampp.
if you are working in server contact to your server provider.

Comment: for php 7.x it is `;extension=sockets`